# QGIS edit line/polygon with digitalize

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

QGIS 3+ has a feature of digitalizing with curve/shape however, it's only available the new lines. How can we utilize this feature when editing lines/polygons? For this reason, I am using QAD plugin, but this is also a very bugged one for QGIS 3, where editing polylines are broken.